# SQL Server store 0 values in Int column or empty value in String and also Date store like 2001-01-01

Tags: c#, sql-server

[Here is my aspx.cs Code behind Class I am Setting properties and set correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViVpm.png)

[Here is my getter/setter properties I get properties in SQL insert see below query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJpmo.png)

Here is my `VoucherSubmit` method that post the form into SQL Server 2012 database:

```
public class InsertData
{
    public void VoucherSubmit()
    {
        myconection mycon = new myconection();
        VoucherForm vr = new VoucherForm();

        string Query1 = "insert into Voucher(VrType,VrDate,CreatedBy,CreationDate,SubmittedBy,SubmittedDate,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate,Method,BillNo,ChequeNo,DemandNo,Branch,AccountDebit,AccountCredit,Debit,Credit,Description)values('" + vr.getvouchertype() + "','" + vr._date + "','" + vr._createdby + "','" + vr.getvoucher_creationdate() + "','" + vr._submittedby + "','" + vr._submitteddate + "','" + vr._approvedby + "','" + vr._approveddate + "','" + vr._method + "','" + vr._billno + "','" + vr._chequeno + "','" + vr._demandno + "','" + vr._branch + "','" + vr._accountdebit + "','" + vr._accountcredit + "','" + vr._debit + "','" + vr._credit + "','" + vr._description + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query1, mycon.GetConnection());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mycon.GetConnection().Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: First: Don't create sqlcommand by concatinating strings because of SQL-Injection. Second: You create a new, empty VoucherForm inside the VoucherSubmit method.

Comment: Thanks For hepling me H.G.Sandhagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing initialized `VoucherForm`, but creating new one in your `VoucherSubmit` method.

```
public void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // All the stuff you have there just change single line
     insert.VoucherSubmit(vf);
}

public void VoucherSubmit(VoucherForm vf)
{
    myconection mycon = new myconection();
    // remove VoucherForm vf = new VoucherForm();
    string Query1 = "insert into Voucher(VrType,VrDate,CreatedBy,CreationDate,SubmittedBy,SubmittedDate,ApprovedBy,ApprovedDate,Method,BillNo,ChequeNo,DemandNo,Branch,AccountDebit,AccountCredit,Debit,Credit,Description)values(@VrType,@VrDate,@CreatedBy,@CreationDate,@SubmittedBy,@SubmittedDate,@ApprovedBy,@ApprovedDate,@Method,@BillNo,@ChequeNo,@DemandNo,@Branch,@AccountDebit,@AccountCredit,@Debit,@Credit,@Description)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query1, mycon.GetConnection());

    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@VrTyp").Value = vr.getvouchertype();
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@VrDate").Value = vr._date;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy").Value = vr._createdby;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreationDate").Value = vr.getvoucher_creationdate();
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SubmittedBy").Value = vr._submittedby;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@SubmittedDate").Value = vr._submitteddate;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApprovedBy").Value = vr._approvedby;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ApprovedDate").Value = vr._approveddate;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Method").Value = vr._method;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@BillNo").Value = vr._billno;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ChequeNo").Value = vr._chequeno;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@DemandNo").Value = vr._demandno;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Branch").Value = vr._branch;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountDebit").Value = vr._accountdebit;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AccountCredit").Value = vr._accountcredit;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Debit").Value = vr._debit;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Credit").Value = vr._credit;
    cmd.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Description").Value = vr._description;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    mycon.GetConnection().Close();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

[Dan Guzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) in the comment suggested to use overload with specified sql data type to avoid performance issues.

> the main point of the article I referenced is that the SqlDbType
>   should be explicitly specified along with the max length in the case
>   of varchar columns. For example,
>
> ```
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@VrDate",
> SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(vr._date,
> "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
> ```
>
> This will ensure the desired data types are
>   passed and avoid excessive cached plans in SQL Server.

Thanks for update!

Related links:

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @cloudikka, would you be kind enough to change your `SqlCommand` to a parameterized query to show the best practice?  Thanks.

Comment: @cloudikka, much better, although [AddWithValue isn't the best method to add parameters](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for performance reasons.

Comment: @DanGuzman I hope now it is better. It would be nice to give an example. Thanks

Comment: @cloudikka, the main point of the article I referenced is that the SqlDbType should be explicitly specified along with the max length in the case of varchar columns. For example, `cmd.Parameters.Add("@VrDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(vr._date, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);`. This will ensure the desired data types are passed and avoid excessive cached plans in SQL Server.

Comment: I added your suggestion to the answer.